# Precision round off in Python

Tags: python, precision

If some Python code's output is in format like `"x.xx"` How to increase its precision ?

eg:

```
import math

tc= int(input())
for i in range(0,tc):
    x1,y1,x2,y2,v1,v2= map(int,input().split())

    #distance
    # d = abs(math.sqrt( abs((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)) + abs((y1-y2)*(y1-y2)) ))

    #d1
    d1 = abs(math.sqrt( abs((x1-x1)*(x1-x2)) + abs((y1-0)*(y1-0)) ))


    #d2
    d2 = abs(math.sqrt( abs((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)) + abs((0-y2)*(0-y2)) ))


    niche = d1/v1
    upar = d2/v2

    roundoff = float("{:.5f}".format(niche+upar))
    print(roundoff)
```

its output is 5.5
make its output as 5.50000.

Comment: I don't quite understand. `print('{:.5f}'.format(5.5))` prints `5.50000` on my machine.

Comment: Just remove the float conversion: `roundoffstr = "{:.5f}".format(niche+upar) ; print(roundoffstr)`

Comment: @AndrejKesely, `print(roundoff)` is pretty printing the float value

Answer (score 2):

`print(roundoff)` is pretty printing the float value.
So you just need to remove the float conversion:

```
roundoffstr = "{:.5f}".format(niche+upar)
print(roundoffstr)
```

Comment: It's the answer, just to supplement it here is a great resource to understand formatting: https://pyformat.info/. And another cool thing with f format: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/